Unconstrained, Constrained Optimization
Suppose I have an objective to maximize $f(q)$, subject to $g(q) \geq 0$. What is the difference between:

First solving the Lagrangian, $L = f(q)$, finding the first-order conditions (FOCs), then setting them to zero to get a solution $q_1^*$, and then check if $g(q_1^*) \geq 0$, if yes, then q_1^* is the solution.

Similarly, calculating the Lagrangian, $L = f(x) + \lambda g(x)$ and finding two solutions through FOCs: $q_{2,\text{binding}}^*$ (when $\lambda > 0$) and $q_{2,\text{nonbinding}}^*$ (when $\lambda = 0$).


Assuming the solutions exist.
My question is, are these two ways of solving are the same? Because I find 1 is more easier than 2 in some cases, what is the benefit of 2? or what extra information can we get from the results from 2?


is just the non binding version of 2.


So 1 plus additional necessary condition $g(q) = 0$ would be the binding version of 2? If so, I guess we can directly solve $q_1^*$ by rearranging $g(q) = 0$, instead of using the FOCs from the Lagrangean?

I doubt that there is a general rule, it depends on the particular problem data.
